# iPhone signature capture

Tags: iphone

My company would dearly like to have an iPhone app which, among other functions, could capture a customer signature.  A web app would be ideal but unfortunately, Mobile Safari doesn't appear to allow mouse movements to be captured by javascript.  It traps them for screen manipulation.  So my question is in two parts:

1. Is there any way a web app could capture a signature from an iPhone?
2. Failing that, is it possible to develop a proprietary iPhone app - one that would be installed only on our own iPhones and not through the App Store?

Comment: Note added Sep 2010: We discovered a company at www.realsignature.com which sells an asp.net web control to do this.  I haven't tried it yet

Comment: Note added October 14/2010: We ended up buying a control from www.supersignature.com.  It was cheaper than RealSignature, has significantly fewer features, but does the basic capture and save to a .jpg, which is all we needed.  It has a wacky copy protection system but the email help is quite good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're willing to have them "sign" using their finger as a pen then yes, on both counts. For the first, you'll probably use a `canvas` tag and the custom touch events generated by Mobile Safari. As the user drags the touch around, you maintain a list of touch points. You draw these as a line list on the canvas for feedback, and submit the list (encoded) as an AJAX postback. Apple gives information on [Mobile Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) touch events; the capture, drawing and transmission, I guess you can handle. You can suppress various Mobile Safari accoutrements with [custom Webkit CSS properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html).

The second, well, it's much the same - only you use a native application, rather than JavaScript. You'll probably get greater touch fidelity, and a smoother user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Adam has pretty much answered your question, but I wanted to point out that iPhone styluses (styli?) are easy to [buy on eBay](http://tw2t.com/19), they are not a rare commodity at all. The special engineering has been done.

A webapp would have no problem with the capture as long as you are using OS 3.0 or greater. Earlier versions might handle it, but I would feel more comfortable committing to being able to make it work smoothly with the later versions.

Unless there were other needs for a proprietary app, I would go webapp all the way.

You can try finger signing yourself on [this widgetpad scribble webapp](http://widgetpad.net/966/play/index.html) to see if you find it acceptable.

Comment: Cool!  The code is a little over my head, but I'll figure it out.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want people to trace out their signatures with their fingers, that's trivial but most people sign with a stylus of some kind. Tracing signatures with touches will produce a different signature than with a stylus.

The problem will be that the iPhone won't work with just any stylus. The screen is uses the body's own innate conductivity to detect touches. You have to use a specially engineered stylus.

Answer (score 1):

Part 2 of your question- You will need an Enterprise iPhone Developer License to deploy the app to your group. There is information on Apple's site regarding the Enterprise Program.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer to your 2nd question, it is possible to deploy to a small group of users (100 or less) using the Ad Hoc deployment method by just adding all of the device UDID's into the devices list on the Apple iOS Provisioning Portal.  You can then distribute the Ad Hoc build to all of the users in that list without using an Enterprise iPhone Developer License.