# Is possible to make digital sign via programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want make digital sign in iphone...is it possible in iphone via xcode...

Comment: Please explain your question more, I can't understand you.

Comment: These questions are duplicate of yours (after deciphering your real requirements from your comments): [iPhone signature capture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132877/iphone-signature-capture) and [iPhone signature capture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664383/iphone-signature-capture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible! See [this tutorial](http://www.riccomini.name/Topics/Mobile/iPhone/SimpleLoginScreen/) for a guide to building a simple login screen on the iPhone.